# Difference between Chrome and IE11 in validating datetime value in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, date, validation, model-view-controller

I have a MVC 5 portal that is in production forced on IE11 (for customer dispositions). Now Chrome become new customer standard and I'm fixing to let it work.

I have a strange situation:

I use jquery datepicker for datetime fields.
In IE11 it works without problem,
In Chrome I get error during validation, it doesn't recognize valid datetime for values like 31/12/2020 (12/12/2020 works probably because it check format mm/dd/yy instead of dd/mm/yy).

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "ActionPlan_f_data_prevision_close", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime f_data_prevision_close { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @type = "textbox" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does anybody know why in IE11 it works meanhwhile in Chrome no?

What I need to Add to let jquery validation check correct date value?

Thank you in advance

Temporary patch:

disabling jquery datepicker and using type="data". The only way to let it works in Chrome for now. In server side I had also date format for SQL that in this case can be disabled as valus is always in yyyy-mm-dd format (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome?hl=en)

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "ActionPlan_f_data_prevision_close", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime? f_data_prevision_close { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}",  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @type = "date", @autocomplete = "off" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.f_data_prevision_close, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the same if I write manually 31/12/2020 or if I pick date from datetime picker.

Comment: The date format displayed to the user is determined by the locale in their browser settings. You should send the date value to the server in a universal format so there's no ambiguity, ie. ISO8601: `2020-12-31T11:23:98.999Z`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem is before to send data to server, is in the browser and jquery validation.

Comment: `@type = "textbox"` is incorrect; it should be `@type = "text"`. IE might be more forgiving than Chrome.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok, anyway forcing to textbox the type chrome correctly use it as text meanwhile with type="date" it use his calendar and the locale is managed by the browser itself.